# Ubuntu doesn't boot since I installed VirtualBox: "A start job is running for Hold..."

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I  installed  VirtualBox  in  my  Ubuntu, and then  when  I  restarted  my PC the screen went purple without ever loading the  login page.

I  see  this  message  when  I  press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

This goes  on  for  20  minutes+.  What  do  I  do  to  fix  this  problem  or  even  troubleshoot?